# How to have each slide in a separate file, each compilable, then combine them

Tags: beamer

I would like to write each slide of a presentation into its own file,
so that I can compile and view each slide, one at a time.
But, I still need to combine all of them to make my presentation.
What's is the way to do that?
I try the following, but it doesn't compile.
`includedoc` doesn't seems to be there in Beamer.

file: 1.tex

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        Content
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

file: slide.tex

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
    \includedoc{1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think what you want is the [`standalone`](http://ctan.org/pkg/standalone) class and package.

Comment: @GarbageCollector: I don't have time to work out an answer now, but I've skimmed the documentation and it mentions beamer a lot.  So I believe it's possible.  Also, the `standalone` author is a prolific `beamer` user (and contributor to this site) so I would not be surprised at all if this is one of his use cases.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Method 1

> The structure of LATEX documents doesn't allow one standalone document to be
>   included as a part of another. `docmute`package tries to remedy this
>   limitation and enables standalone documents to be imported with the
>   standard `\input` and `\include` commands just as if they had no preamble.

Use `docmute` package in the main input file. `docmute` package will import everything between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` of the imported file (`child.tex` in the following example). You can still compile the `child.tex` as a standalone presentation.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{child.tex}
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        Content
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{docmute}
\begin{document}
    \input{child}
\end{document}
```

### Method 2

Using `standalone` document class with option `beamer` for the child (imported) input file and using package `standalone` in the main input file.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{child.tex}
\documentclass[beamer]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        Content
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \input{child}
\end{document}
```

Note: using the first method seems to be simpler!

Comment: You've formatted the first paragraph like a blockquote; is it from some other documentation?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: yes. but i edited a bit for clearness.

Comment: What are you quoting from, then?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: I quoted the first paragraph in the introduction section of `docmute` package.

Comment: Ah, so you did.  Links are always good, though. :-)

Comment: `standalone` class and package can be regarded as a combination of `preview`, `docmute` plus a feature for collecting preamble from the child input files.

Comment: dope answer, thanks for this

Answer (score 7):

One option, but I am not sure if this is *exactly* what you are after, would be to label the frames so that you can use `\includeonlyframes`; a little example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\includeonlyframes{one,three}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[label=one]
test frame one.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label=two]
test frame two.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label=three]
test frame three.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label=four]
test frame four.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Using the code above, only the two frames corresponding to the labels `one` and `three` will be shown.

Combining this idea with the use of `\include` (or `\input`), you then might write each frame contents in its own file; something like

```
\begin{frame}[label=two]
the frame contents...
\end{frame}
```

(notice, in particular that this subsidiary files have no `\documentclass`, nor `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}` commands); each of this files will then be saved in your current working directory as, for example, `frameone.tex`, `frametwo.tex`, `framethree.tex`, `framefour.tex` and then you can `\include` them in the desired order in your "main" document; for example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\include{frametwo}
\include{framefour}
\include{framethree}
\include{frameone}

\end{document}
```

will show the four frames in the order `two`, `four`, `three`, `one`.

The following code

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\includeonlyframes{one,three}

\begin{document}

\include{frametwo}
\include{framefour}
\include{framethree}
\include{frameone}

\end{document}
```

will give you a two frame document showing the frames in the order `three`, `one`.