# Splitting the preamble

Tags: beamer, pdfpages, include, preamble, subfiles

When working with big documents, especially when dealing with many lists, graphics, figures and includes, I often come up with a structure roughly looking like this.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

[preamble for part 1]
[preamble for part 2]
[preamble for part 3]
....

\begin{document}
[part 1 body]
[part 2 body]
[part 3 body]
...
\end{document}
```

A usual practise is to export the body parts to single files and then `\include` them.

The `subfiles` package provides a more comfortable approach by making it possible to compiled the parts independently reusing the preamble of the main file. But `subfiles` discards the preambles of the subfiles. To make it possible to both modularize preamble and body, each body part must be exported to a subfile `part1.tex` and each preamble part to a corresponding package `part1.sty`. The document is then stitched together using `\include` and `\usepackage`.

Ideally, preamble and body of the parts should be kept together. Compiling individual pdfs then to connect with `\includepdf` comes somewhat close to this, but is hard to use especially with `beamer` when the whole document should be produced in handout mode or with notes. Dealing with overlays or providing a correct table of contents is even more cumbersome.

How I really would like to structure the document is along the lines of this.

```
%main.tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\include{part1}
\include{part2}
....


%part1.tex
\documentclass{beamer}
[part 1 preamble]
\begin{document}
[part 1 body]
\end{document}


%part2.tex
\documentclass{beamer}
[part 2 preamble]
\begin{document}
[part 2 body]
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to realize this scheme? Could it even be possible to realize it and be able to compile the parts independently?

Comment: maybe the `standalone` could be useful here; related: [How to have each slide in a separate file, each compilable, then combine them](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102384)

Answer (score 1):

Check the package [`docmute`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/docmute). It is close to what you want as long as the preamble for the main file  includes all the other preambles

**`main.tex`**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\input{fullpreamble}
\usepackage{docmute}
\begin{document}
\input{doc1.tex}
\input{doc2.tex}
\end{document}
```

**`doc1.tex`**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\input{fullpreamble}
\begin{document}
body1
\end{document}
```

**`doc2.tex`**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\input{fullpreamble}
\begin{document}
body2
\end{document}
```

This allows you to compile all the parts independently.